# Eligiblity of Sāmagāna (सामगान​)

Tags: sama-veda

Sāmaveda includes sāmagāna which is singing of [Ruchas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richa).

Who is eligible for chanting or singing of Sāmans? Is it only a Sāmavedi Brahmana or other Brahmanas can chant them too?

Also, is every [dwija](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvija) eligible for sāmagāna?